# Ne pas exprimer l'antériorité avec le plus-que-parfait

Tags: temps-grammatical, concordance-des-temps

I'm familiar with the plus-que-parfait and its anteriority. If X is a reference point in the past, then the plus-que-parfait verb took place further back than X.

However, I sometimes hear it without any obvious anteriority. A common  example seems to be « j'avais pensé », which I feel should be « je pensais » :

> J'avais pensé que tu viendrais aujourd'hui.

I see that I'm not the only one to be confused by this; [here's a relevant WordReference thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/javais-pens%C3%A9-que-je-pensais-que.2535209/).

The last poster there says this is because the X reference point (« ... avant de me rendre compte que ... ») is implied. But surely that would legitimate the plus-que-parfait all over the place where there's no obvious grammatical reason to use it! Can't we find invisible clauses anywhere we look?

1. Is this "non-anterior PQP" standard, or familiar or mistaken (from a prescriptivist point of view)?
2. If it's legitimate, is it isolated to « j'avais pensé » and/or some other small class of verbs, or can you do this with any verb?
3. As always, is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cet emploi du plus-que-parfait exprime bien une antériorité et n'est pas réservé à « j'avais pensé ». Il s'agit d'une antériorité par rapport au moment présent. 
 Grevisse (*Le bon usage*) dit que « dans ce cas, le moment présent est en quelque sorte considéré comme déjà tombé dans le passé ».

Je dis très souvent :

> Il pleut, je l'**avais** bien **dit**.

Un des exemples donné dans *Le bon usage*:

> Me voici pris : on m'**avait** pourtant **averti**. (Corneille, *Cinna*).

Je marche dans une flaque :

> Mince, je ne l'**avais pas vue** !

Il y a un emploi relativement fréquent du plus-que-parfait qui ne marque pas d’antériorité explicite par rapport à un autre fait, c'est pour faire une demande polie. Par exemple, je pars en vacances et je vais sonner chez mes voisins :

> J'**étais venu** vous demander si vous pourriez prendre mon courrier pendant mon absence.

On pourrait exprimer la même chose avec un imparfait :

> Je venais vous demander si ....

ou encore avec le présent :

> Je viens vous demander si....

Le présent est le plus « direct », l'imparfait, en marquant une certaine distance avec le présent, atténue le sans-gêne que représente la demande, le plus-que-parfait, l'atténue encore plus.

Comment: Alors il me faudra juste accepter que « le moment présent peut être déjà dans le passé » ! Pas de comparaison donc avec l'anglais que le considère comme erroné. Merci comme toujours.